# Double pointer to 2D

Tags: arrays, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I have an an integer array of values and I would like to make a double pointer to point to this array. I assume that this 1D integer array actually represents a 2D array. That is for instance that if I have an `int A[2000*12]` then I have 12 lines and 2000 rows. The problem is that I do not know how to initialize the pointer to point to the array A. My initial thought was like that:

```
  int A[2000*12];
  int **ptr;
  ptr=&A[0];
```

Of course this is not correct. More precisely I get the following error: 
incompatible pointer types in assignment

Comment: When you do `ptr=&A[0]` you are taking the address of the first element(`int *`). I don't know why you want double pointer to single dimensional array.

Comment: I need this because this is a part of a bigger program. I actually try to run a program into a different processor architecture(VLIW). To do this i have to pass some arguments of a function through a given library function. Initially i had a double pointer. Then i passed all the data from the double pointer to a 1D array and now i have to get these data back to a double pointer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [0] part:

```
int A[2000*12];
int **ptr;
ptr = &A;
```

EDIT:
This however does not solve the problem with getting a 2D array. You still can't access it like

```
A[1][2] = 10;
```

because the compiler does not know the length of rows.

My favourite way of initializing a 2D array goes like:

```
int width = 10;
int height = 20;
int *_a = (int *) malloc(width * height * sizeof(int));
int **a = (int **) malloc(height * sizeof(int *));
```

The first allocation creates the 2D array, the second one creates an array pointing to each row.

```
int i, offset = 0;
for (i = 0; i < height; i++, offset += width)
{
    a[i] = _a + offset;
}

a[0][0] = 1;
a[0][1] = 2;
a[1][0] = 2;
a[1][1] = 4;
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to explain the problem again. Initially i had a double pointer which represents a double array of 2000 lines and 12 rows. Then i passed the data from this double pointer into a 1D array. So that in this 1D array i will have in the first 12 elements the first line , then for index=13 until 13+12 i will have the second line etc. Finally i want to find a way to extract these data from the 1D array back to a double pointer!

Comment: Edited the answer. Take a look at the for cycle. If I get your question right, this may solve your problem as it performs the expected conversion from a 1D to a 2D (double pointer) array.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please mark the question as solved if you find it answered.

Comment: How can i do that? Sorry This was actually my first post so I am kind of new here .